# Insert data from gridview into database

Tags: vb.net

Using SQL Server 2014, VS 2012, VB, n-layer

I import data from a CSV file into a gridview, which then gets inserted into a temporary table in a SQL Server database.

All of this works fine, as shown by the code below but with one major shortcoming. The code cycles through the rows in the gridview and inserts one row of data from the gridview at a time, which means that it will open a connection to the database, insert the row, and close the connection.

If I have 100 rows of data in the gridview, that will mean it will open and close a  connection to the database 100 times, which seems to be a very inefficient way of doing things. What I really need to do is insert all the rows in bulk, with only one open and close operation.

This is where I'm having problems. Do I load the rows into a datatable? How then to pass the contents of the datatable onto my BLL and DAL layers?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

UI:

```
Dim myTemporaryPatient As TemporaryPatient
myTemporaryPatient = New TemporaryPatient

For i As Integer = 0 To grdQuad.Rows.Count - 1
myTemporaryPatient.TempDEPM = grdQuad.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text

myTemporaryPatient.TempDateRecordAdded = Now()
myTemporaryPatient.TempPIDSurname = grdQuad.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text
myTemporaryPatient.TempPIDForename = grdQuad.Rows(i).Cells(2).Text
myTemporaryPatient.TempPIDNHSNo = grdQuad.Rows(i).Cells(3).Text
myTemporaryPatient.TempPIDDoB = grdQuad.Rows(i).Cells(4).Text
myTemporaryPatient.TempResult = grdQuad.Rows(i).Cells(5).Text
myTemporaryPatient.TempHospital = grdQuad.Rows(i).Cells(6).Text
myTemporaryPatient.TempDateOfResult = grdQuad.Rows(i).Cells(7).Text
myTemporaryPatient.TempLRisk = grdQuad.Rows(i).Cells(8).Text
myTemporaryPatient.TempRisk=GetNullableInt(grdQuad.Rows(i).Cells(9).Text)
myTemporaryPatient.TempLTrisomy18 = grdQuad.Rows(i).Cells(10).Text
myTemporaryPatient.TempTrisomy18=GetNullableInt(grdQuad.Rows(i).Cells(11).Text)
myTemporaryPatient.TempTestType = "Quad"

TemporaryPatientManager.InsertTemporaryPatient(myTemporaryPatient)

Next
```

DAL:

```
Public Shared Function InsertTemporaryPatient(ByVal myTemporaryPatient As LettersBusinessEntities.TemporaryPatient) As Integer

    Dim myTemporaryPatientRecord As LettersBusinessEntities.TemporaryPatient = Nothing
    Using myConnection As New SqlConnection(ApplicationConfiguration.ConnectionString)
        Using myCommand As New SqlCommand("SPInsertIntoTemporaryPatient", myConnection)
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TempDEPM", myTemporaryPatient.TempDEPM)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TempDateRecordAdded", myTemporaryPatient.TempDateRecordAdded)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TempPIDSurname", myTemporaryPatient.TempPIDSurname)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TempPIDForename", myTemporaryPatient.TempPIDForename)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TempPIDNHSNo", myTemporaryPatient.TempPIDNHSNo)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TempPIDDoB", myTemporaryPatient.TempPIDDoB)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TempResult", myTemporaryPatient.TempResult)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TempHospital", myTemporaryPatient.TempHospital)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TempLRisk", myTemporaryPatient.TempLRisk)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TempRisk", myTemporaryPatient.TempRisk)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TempLTrisomy18", myTemporaryPatient.TempLTrisomy18)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TempTrisomy18", myTemporaryPatient.TempTrisomy18)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TempTestType", myTemporaryPatient.TempTestType)

            myConnection.Open()
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End Using
        myConnection.Close()

    End Using
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: open connection before 'For i As Integer = 0' and close after 'next'

Comment: Thanks for the response. All the CRUD operations, including opening and closing database connections, are handled in the DAL, so I'm unsure how I'd go about implementing your suggestion.

Comment: How about populate a DataTable (dt) based on the temp table, add the CSV records to the dt, use dt as the datasource for the grid, make the edits and save the dt adds/updates.

Comment: Thanks. I've just been told that the CSV file will not have a header row, which was previously not the case. Makes things harder.

Comment: Look into TVP for SQL.  you can pass the table as a parameter and CRUD the entire thing at once.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I came across this possible solution last night. I'm testing now but having some issues.

Comment: OK, so after much testing, swearing and throwing of objects across the office, I've switched to SQLBulkCopy, which is now working as I want it to. Thanks for the suggestions.